# How do I find the text changes in TFS 2005 history?

Tags: tfs, diff

I'm wondering how I search history in TFS 2005 for any changeset that contains a change (diff) between the file and it's previous version with the word "foobar" in it.

In other words, and more specifically, I want to find the changeset that removed a subscription to an event. Clearly the change won't be in the class raising the event, and because the event subscription is now gone, I don't know where it used to be.

I can probably narrow this down to a few hundred files, but viewing their individual history and then performing a difference on each seems excessive. The TF history command, even in detailed view, only shows me file names.

```
tf history /format:detailed *.* /noprompt /stopafter:1
```

Is there an undocumented uber-detailed output that shows a diff of each file with it's previous version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in TFS 2005. You would have to write a program that retrieved the history for the chosen file and for each changeset in the history of the file, it would have to retrieve the version in the changeset and the previous version, and diff the two to determine the changes made and compare them with the text change sought.